# How to understand error messages for "1.2 % 3.4" for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

How to understand error messages for "1.2 % 3.4" for Haskell?

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Ratio
Prelude Data.Ratio> 4.3 % 1.2

<interactive>:11:1:
    No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘print’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Show Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus 23 others
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
Prelude Data.Ratio>
```

Comment: Maybe you should directly set type of expression? (4.3 % 1.2)::Float or smth. Maybe haskell cannot deriving type for this expression

Comment: Of all the error messages ghc gives, this is one of the worst. It tells you nothing about the actual problem. The type of your expression is `(Integral a, Fractional a) => Ratio a`. However, there is no type which is both an `Integral` and a `Fractional. Defaulting fails (it should really tell you that) and it emits an error for the expression `print (4.3 % 1.2)`, not what you actually typed. Your problem is `Ratio` is the ratio of two *integers*, so `4.3 % 1.2` doesn't make any sense. `4 % 3` or the like works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type error message is a little unfriendly, me thinks.

What is actually happening here is that your expression has type

```
Prelude Data.Ratio> :t 4.3 % 1.2
4.3 % 1.2 :: (Integral a, Fractional a) => Ratio a
```

`Integral a` means your type `a` has to be integer-like, while `Fractional a` means that it has to be floating-point or rational-like. There are no types in standard Haskell which are both.

When evaluating this expression in order to print it, GHCi first infers its type, with the additional restriction that it needs to printable:

```
(Integral a, Fractional a, Show a) => Ratio a
```

Now since this is still too ambiguous to evaluate, GHCi tries *defaulting* `a` to either `Integer` or `Double`. But neither of them fits here, each is a member of just one of the classes `Integral` and `Fractional`.

Then, after failing at defaulting, GHCi gives an error message that tells you *one* of the constraints it was failing to satisfy. And particularly confusingly, it happens to choose the one which has nothing to do with why it failed...

Anyway, to fix your problem: `%` is *not* the function to divide two rationals, it is the function to construct a rational from an integer-like numerator and denominator.  To *divide* them instead, use

```
4.3 / 1.2 :: Rational
```

The `:: Rational` tells GHCi that you want a rational (rather than the default `Double` it would otherwise choose), and floating-point notation *does* work to make a `Rational` - it is one of the features the `Fractional` typeclass provides.